# Is it possible to loop over files with a literalinclude code block?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a folder of templates and I'd like to loop over all of them and display their contents on a page. I'm not *rendering* the templates' I'm displaying these templates' raw content as jinja code blocks.

I could do this for each one:

```
    .. literalinclude :: ../mytemplates/template_one.j2
       :language: jinja
```

But new templates could be added and others removed and there are many of them.

How can I loop over a folder of jinja templates and embed their contents as code blocks on a page?

Comment: If you consider maintaining a list of template files, update the list when templates are added or removed, you can take a look at https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/datatemplates